# Default headers not being applied in Spring Boot WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers, webclient

I am experiencing an issue with the WebClient class in my Spring Boot application. I have set default headers on the WebClient instance using the defaultHeaders method in the WebClient.Builder, but the headers are not being applied to requests made by the WebClient.

Instead, I have to manually add the headers to each request using the header method.

Here is an example of how I am setting the default headers:

```
public EService() {
this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(baseURL)
        .defaultHeaders(header -> {
            header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            header.set("api-key", apiKey);
        })
        .build();
```

}

Here is the example, how i use the method with default headers:

```
public List<NetworksResponseItemObject> getAllNetworks() {
    List<NetworksResponseItemObject> results = new LinkedList<>();


    try {
        List<NetworksResponseObject> response = webClient.get().uri( orgID + "/hvs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<NetworksResponseObject>>() {})
                .block(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

        for (NetworksResponseObject networksResponseObject : response) {
            results.addAll(networksResponseObject.getNetworks());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new LinkedList<>(); //If there´s an error, we return an empty list
    }return results;}
```

If i use this, i get a 400 Error, BadRequest

If i delete the default headers and add them in every method like this it´s working:
public List getAllNetworks() {
List results = new LinkedList<>();

```
try {
    List<NetworksResponseObject> response = webClient.get()
            .uri(orgID + "/hvs")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .header("api-key", apiKey)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<NetworksResponseObject>>() {})
            .block(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

    for (NetworksResponseObject networksResponseObject : response) {
        results.addAll(networksResponseObject.getNetworks());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    return new LinkedList<>(); //If there's an error, we return an empty list
}

log.info("Found " + results.size() + " networks");
return results;
```

}

Why is it like this? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Method defaultHeaders operates on a map of type HttpHeaders. Try this:

```
this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(baseURL)
    .defaultHeaders(headers -> {
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.add("api-key", apiKey);
    })
    .build();
```

Alternatively use the method defaultHeader this way:

```
this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(baseURL)
    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .defaultHeader("api-key", apiKey)
    .build();
```